# locationでhttpsに移動させたい

Tags: php, apache

phpのheader関数でhttpからhttpsに移動させたいです
submitだとhttpsに移動できます。

`header(location:https://example.com)`だと移動はしますが、
[http://example.comに移動してしまいます](http://example.com%E3%81%AB%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)。

headerのlocationの設定の前に何か必要なのでしょうか？
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');とか加えてみましたがうまくいかず・・・

後ありえない、[https://example_example.php等ないファイルにアクセスしたら](https://example_example.php%E7%AD%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89)、httpsでした・・・わかりません。

Comment: お試しになったPHPのコードを開示していただくことはできますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ここに記述されたとおりであるとすれば、

```
header("location :https://example.com");
```

は誤りで

```
header("location: https://example.com");
```

が正しいですね。
locationの後のスペースとコロンが逆です。
前者はMac上のChromeで正しく遷移できませんでした。

一度お試しください。

また、headerのlocationですが、解釈しているのはapacheではなく各ブラウザです。
ブラウザが受け取ったレスポンス内のヘッダーを解釈して、指定のURLへリダイレクトしてくれているのです。
なので、本件に関してはapacheの設定は関係ありません。
詳しくは下記を参照してください。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections

Comment: こんばんは、ありがとうございます。スペースとコロンを変えてみます。後、ありえないhttpsに飛ばしたらいきました。飛んだ先のクラスで書き換えられてるのかなとおもってるんですが・・・はまっています。